# Django get query from queryset. Returning invalid params

Tags: python, sql-server, django

When I try to get the query from django queryset, it returns parameters without quotes which makes it an invalid query to run

I have a django code as follows:

```
qs = Sample.objects.filter(data_date__range=[start_date, end_date])
```

When I try to get the query so that I can query it using pyodbc (I found django's query taking 5 seconds vs pyodbc taking <1 for 50k+ rows), I try to get the query like this:

```
str(qs.query)
```

However, for the parameters it returns without quotes for example the query returned is

```
SELECT * FROM [sample] WHERE [data_date] 
BETWEEN 2019-01-01 00:00:00 AND 2022-01-01 00:00:00
```

As is evident, the quotes are missing from the 2 datetime variables so when I try to run the query using `pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)` then I get an error pointing to these parameters. And it's not just date param, if I try to filter using anything else, I get the same issue.

#### Error when querying without quotes

```
Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM [sample] WHERE [sample].[data_date] BETWEEN 2019-01-01 00:00:00 AND 2022-01-01 00:00:00': ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '00'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

I was wondering whether there's any other way to generate the query from django queryset so that I can run it using pyodbc or anything else to get a faster result.

I'm using `Django 3.2` and `sql-server`

#### Update:

Indexes on the DB

```
...
[sample_data_date] (Non-unique, Non-clustered)
AK (Unique, Non-clustered)
PK (clustered)
...
```

Comment: Add a `db_index=True` on the `data_date` field.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's already added! Still quite slow

Comment: The quotes do not matter.

Comment: I just updated the question to reflect the error I get when querying using `pd.read_sql(query, conn)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I found the answer to my own question.
Posting here so others won't have to search as much as I did.

Turns out that `queryset.query` doesn't return valid SQL. We need to use `.sql_with_params()` to get the query and parameters separately.

The final code looked something like this:

```
qs = Sample.objects.filter(data_date__range=[start_date, end_date])
query, params = qs.query.sql_with_params()

# pyodbc uses "?" vs django returns "%s" as placeholder
query = query.replace("%s", "?")

df = pd.read_sql(query, pyodbc_conn, params=params)
```

Querying using pyodbc like this took <1 second vs using Django ORM taking 5 seconds for 56000 rows x 5 columns.

Big help from [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17741) Django ticket.